# Display results only on search

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, getjson

I need the search results div to only show when results of a search have been returned (not when the user is searching a term), and then be able to clear the results divs when a new term is searched.

I should be able to use something like `$(".results").empty()`, but this will keep the results div always blank.

```
$("#searchterm").keyup(function(e) {
  var q = $("#searchterm").val();
  //Only begin search with at least 3 characters.
  if (q.length > 3) {
    ajax_search();
  }
  //Send search query
  function ajax_search() {
    $.getJSON("//url-to-search?q=" + q, {},
      //Get results and make 'em look good
      function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        //  $(".results").append("Results for <b> " + q + "</b>");
        $.each(data.data, function(i, data) {
          if (data.type === "category-1") {
            if ($(".category-1").text() == '') {
              $(".category-1-results-header, .category-1").hide()
            }
            $(".category-1").append("<li class='result-item'><a href=\"localhost:4000" + data.permalink + "\">" + data.title + "</a></li>");
          } else if (data.type === "category-2") {
            $(".category-2").append("<li class='result-item'><a href=\"localhost:4000" + data.permalink + "\">" + data.title + "</a></li>");
            if ($(".category-2").text() == '') {
              $(".category-2-results-header, .category-2").hide()
            }
          } else if (data.type === "category-3") {
            $(".category-3").append("<li class='result-item'><a href=\"localhost:4000" + data.permalink + "\">" + data.title + "</a></li>");
            if ($(".category-3").text() == '') {
              $(".category-3-results-header, .category-3").hide()
            }
          }
        });
      });
  }
});
```

**JSFIDDLE: [LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/yp58f9qu/)**

Comment: You can include a `<button>` or other element to perform request when user clicks element, instead of using `keyup` event, which makes request if `input` element `.length` is greater than `3`

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like

```
if (q.length > 3) {
    ajax_search();
} else {
    $(".results").empty();
}
```

Comment: Approach would still make request while user is typing where `.length` of `q` is greater than `3`?

Comment: Doing this clears the results in general. I need to hide the `<div class="results"></div>` until the user has typed more than three characters, and clear each results div when the user types a new query